# Docker hangs forever during pulling image layers

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I am trying to build docker image, but docker hangs forever during downloading image layers:

[image]

I tried this several times, and it just stops downloading at different points. I also tried `docker-machine restart` without any effect.

I am using docker machine on Mac OS X:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
$ docker-machine -v
docker-machine version 0.5.5, build 02c4254
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same issue right now. No idea how to fix it either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try other docker images to locate the issues (may have connection issues to this docker images), also increase the memory for the VM

Comment: I used to have this problem all the time, but never with docker > 1.12  and docker-machine 0.8.0. Does this still occur?

Comment: Which filesystem do you use for Docker? I was seeing this with *overlayFS*. And does this happen for all images or just specific ones?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I've switched from using `Docker Toolbox` to `Docker For Mac` and now it runs smoothly.

Here's a comparison: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/

Also make sure you have the latest Docker For Mac